# El atributo de validación del teléfono no funciona [Phone]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo el siguiente modelo

```
public class MiModelo 
{
    [Phone(ErrorMessage = "Ingresa un teléfono válido")]
    public int Telefono1 { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> Telefono2 { get; set; } // acepta valores nulos
    public Nullable<int> Telefono3 { get; set; } // acepta valores nulos
}
```

El cual envió desde mi formulario a la vista con solo un único dato que seria el `Telefono1` (como dato le paso 130223680) al llegar a mi `controller` valido el modelo recibido de la forma:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return Json(model);
```

El cual en vez de saltarse el `return` esta entrando al `if`, por ende se entiende que el modelo viene erróneo.

Hice la prueba sin el `[Phone()]` y funciona perfecto, por ende el problema estaría al aplicarle este filtro a la propiedad. ¿Cual seria un `phone` correcto para que tome el modelo como valido?

Los datos que estoy enviando es el que puse en () mas arriba.

En `Telefono1` lo envio con un 130223680

En `Telefono2` lo envio `null`

En `Telefono3` lo envio `null`

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar los datos que estás enviando?

Comment: Listo, ahí coloque los valores con que los envió.

Comment: el tipo de dato int para un numero de telefono es correcto? no deberia ser un string? ya que si empieza en cero, el int se lo va a comer. Ademas no creo que los numeros de telefono quepan en un int.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una expresion regular y si el teléfono deberia ser String por que el tipo de dato int solo soporta hasta el número 32,767 por eso te marca que el modelo es invalido

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Telefono")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid phone number")]
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
```